# writing and saving new custom EXIF and IPTC tags in android

Tags: android, metadata, exif, iptc

I have a camera and gallery image which I store in my device and then send to server.

I need to add some photographer information that will be entered via `edittext` and sent with the `image` as `metadata`.

I have searched everywhere and I got results how to write `metadata` using `sanselan` but in the existing tags.

I coul'nt find anything about writing new custom `tags` to the images.

please provide me a sample code if anybody has it.

Comment: ExifInterface ?

Comment: is there any way to add description tag to ExifInterface